# Upgrade MacBook 7,1 RAM using old HP laptop RAM

Tags: macbook-pro

I have an old broken HP laptop from which I want to take its RAM and put it in a MacBook 7,1 and the RAM meets the specification that OWC recommends.

Comment: If the specs match and the physical dimensions are correct try it - if it fails you won't hear the startup chimes in the "normal" format.

Comment: Is there a question here?  if you are looking for validation on your findings, you need to include *details* like model of HP and the specs of the RAM.  As the question is written, it's quite vague.